# Heavyhanded URL Rewrite kills php scripting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This must be a common noob problem but I don't know how to properly handle this.

I want it so no matter what the user places on the url line when accessing our offline activation server, the are sent to /offline.php.

While this one global rule works, it kills the script. I suppose it should but I don't know to fix it. I see the offline.php page as I should but none of the buttons do anything etc.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* /offline.php
```

Comment: How do you know if the activation server is offline?

Comment: It should be sending _any_ request to /offline.php, along with the original Query String (if any). You say that you _are_ seeing the offline.php page, but it seems to be dead? No response to any button? Is it an HTML form that's being put up? Where does it send the form data (action= )? Is it coming back to the same server, going through this .htaccess again, and putting up offline.php again? If so, you would have to add a RewriteCond to exclude the action script from being redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(offline\.php|\.js\.css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /offline.php [L]
```